# Move a flask server to production with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I followed this [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/). Here is my server:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When running

```
python server.py
curl 127.0.0.1:5000
```

I get the expected result.

Now I add a test.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/test')
from server import app as application
```

and in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.config:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
ServerName example.com

WSGIDaemonProcess test user=user1 group=user1 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test/test.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/test>
    WSGIProcessGroup test
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now calling

```
sudo service apache2 restart
curl 127.0.0.1:5000
```

will return an error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that Apache is listening on port 5000 at all? And you'll almost certainly need to remove that ServerName directive.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I posted the answer below. (I'm not allowed to mark it as the correct answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman pointed out, I needed to

1. Remove the ServerName directive
2. Add `Listen 5000` to my `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` to make the server listen on port 5000